# Convert Bazaar repo to Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bazaar, mercurial-convert

I'm using GUI's to handle my version control. Currently I'm using Bazaar Explorer (GUI for bzr) , but I'd like to use TortoiseHG (GUI for hg).

For Windows users like me, I found several indication that this can be done via the command line using:

```
hg convert file:///C:\my_bzr_repo
```

where I made sure the 'convert' extension for TortoiseHG is enabled. However, this does not work. I get the following error message:

```
file:///C:\my_bzr_repo does not look like a Bazaar repository
```

Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure `C:\my_bzr_repo` is a Bazaar repository? Is there a `.bzr` directory inside?

Comment: Something else to check is whether that file URL is correct. I'm not sure mixing your slashes like that will work. Have you tried just giving it the path without the `file:///` prefix?

Comment: @janos : inside `my_bzr_repo` is a `trunk` folder and a hidden `.bzr` folder which is the Bazaar repository.

Comment: @dOxxx : I tried several paths like `C:\my_bzr_repo\trunk` or `C:\my_bzr_repo\.bzr` but they all give the same error message. With or without the `file:///` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. For other's that have this problem, here's what I did:

1. Uninstalled TortoiseHg (because the `hg convert` command called the Hg scripts from TortoiseHg)
2. Followed [these steps](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Bazaar).
3. Reinstalled TortoiseHg, opened the newly created Hg repo
4. (Optional) I had to clone the Hg repo in order to copy all the files I wached in the correct directory.

Apparently you'll need the Python (2.7) module of Mercurial in order to make the `hg convert` command work.